# Cannot create tables through PopSQL - ER_PHRASE_ERROR

Tags: mysql, syntax, syntax-error, popsql

I'm completely new to SQL and trying to learn online. I'm trying to create tables in MySQL through PopSQL, but I keep getting a syntax error. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Picture attached for reference. Any help will be appreciated.

My query is:

```
CREATE TABLE studentinfo ();
```

And the error I get when trying to run it is:

```
ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
```

[Link for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEdGK.jpg)

Comment: You need to include at least one column in the table, e.g. CREATE TABLE test(c1 int not null);

Comment: Right! I get what I was doing wrong. Many thanks, kind sir.